# CentOS 8 remote logging logs on both custom log and /var/log/messages

Tags: logging, remote, rsyslog, centos8

I'm trying to configure a remote log host for my servers (all CentOS 8). I added this on my central server

```
if $fromhost-ip == '123.123.123.123' then /var/log/{{hostname}}.log
```

Also I changed my client config to

```
*.* @@321.321.321.321:514/var/log/{{hostname}}.log
```

But when I try to run:

```
sudo logger "test"
```

It both logs on /var/log/hostname.log and /var/log/messages on my central remote server

It also floods the custom log file with

```
pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by admin(uid=0)
log message here
pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

How do I set my logs only to send to my custom log file? And how do I filter these pam messages to be not included?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging to multiple locations is perfectly allowed, so if you did not change the default configuration which logs most things to `/var/log/messages`, then they will continue to be logged there.

The config file `/etc/rsyslog.conf` contains, among other things:

```
# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
```

You might add a [property-based filter](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html#property-based-filters) to discard messages after you have logged them once, based on [various properties](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/properties.html) of the message. For example: After logging it once, the property-based filter will discard the message, preventing later configurations from logging it (the tilde means to discard the message and not process it further):

```
:fromhost-ip, isequal, '123.123.123.123' /var/log/{{hostname}}.log
:fromhost-ip, isequal, '123.123.123.123' ~
```

---

You're getting pam messages, because you used `sudo`, not because you ran `logger`. You will get those every time you run `sudo`. If you do not want to see them in the log, do not run `sudo`. It isn't necessary to use `sudo` to run `logger` anyway.

Comment: Hi, I tried replacing my config to what you gave me but now it won't store the logs on my custom log file, but it's still logged on my messages log. Do I have to create another

`:fromhost-ip, isequal, '127.0.0.1' /var/log/messages`

so it will be separated from each other?

Comment: @Gwynn What changes did you make to your configuration?

Comment: this one: `:fromhost-ip, isequal, '123.123.123.123' /var/log/{{hostname}}.log`

I tried changing it using `if $fromhost-ip == 123.123.123.123 then /var/log/{{hostname}}.log ` and `if $fromhost-ip == 123.123.123.123 then ~` but it still logs on both logfile, do I have to change my central server's log file so it logs on a separate log file and not messages?

Comment: Tried this [link](https://www.rsyslog.com/article60/) now I have three log files with the same content? I'm getting confused.

Comment: I'm dumb, I just had to place it before the default rules so it would "hit" the ~ first before entering the other rules. Thanks man!